# How can I temporarily disable clang-format include sorting?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am changing my project from using Artistic Style to **clang-format**. One feature I'm excited to use is include file sorting. However, there's one issue I don't know how to get around. I'm using **clang-format** 7.0.1 on CentOS 7 (from **llvm-toolset-7.0** in the SCLo repository).

Our standard states that in a class header the base class will be included first. We then included "system"(ish) headers, followed by local directory, and libraries in decreasing order of coupling. I want to change the standard to be more in line with the [llvm guidelines](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#include-style).

The problem is that I don't know how to force my base class(es) to remain first in the header. I'm willing to modify every class header (once) if that is what is required.

Here is a sample input file, manually constructed according to the old project standards:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "util/Application.hh"
#include "ZMQmixin.hh"

#include <filesystem>
#include <json/json.h>

#include "ZMQconfig.hh"
#include "ZMQendpoint.hh"
#include "Platform.hh"

#include "Foo/bar.hh"

#include "icd/Published.hh"
#include "icd/NavPoint.hh"

class Sample : public Application
             , public ZMQmixin
{
    using Base = Application;
public:
    Sample(int num_io_threads = 1);
};
```

Here is a minimal **.clang-format** file that I'm using to sort my includes:

```
Language:                                       Cpp
BreakBeforeBraces:                              Allman

AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType:           None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType:                     TopLevelDefinitions

BreakInheritanceList:                           BeforeComma

SortIncludes:                                   true
IncludeBlocks:                                  Merge # Regroup # or Preserve ?
IncludeCategories:
  # include file order:
  #    1 current directory ("Foo.hh")
  #    2 parent directory -- only in unit tests ("../Foo.hh")
  #    5 other directory   ("bar/Baz.hh")
  #   15 osw|Common/*.hh
  #   20 icd/*.hh
  #   30 util/*.hh
  #   40 <pseudo/system.h> (boost, armadillo, zmq, etc.)
  #   45 <c++include>
  #   46 <cwrapper>  (cmath, etc.)
  #   50 <c-include.h>
  #   55 <other/include.h>

  ## Regexes must be ordered so that the most specific pattern matches first,
  ## when multiple patterns might match

  # current dir
  - Regex:           '^"[[:alnum:]]+\.hh'
    Priority:        1

  # parent dir (unit test)
  - Regex:           '^"\.\.\/[[:alnum:]_-]+'
    Priority:        2

  # project headers, in decreasing order of coupling
  - Regex:           '^"(osw|Common)/'
    Priority:        15
  - Regex:           '^"icd/'
    Priority:        20
  - Regex:           '^"util/'
    Priority:        30

  # any other "x/y.hh" header is assumed to be a project header, but very coupled
  - Regex:           '^"[[:alnum:]]+/'
    Priority:        5

  # pseudo system headers
  - Regex:           '^(<|")(boost|armadillo|json|zmq)/'
    Priority:        40

  # override for C++ headers that begin with 'c' and lack any special character
  - Regex:           '^<(chrono|compare|charconv|complex)>'
    Priority:        45
  # C-language headers
  - Regex:           '^<c[a-z]+>'
    Priority:        46
  # C++ language headers
  - Regex:           '^<([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)>'
    Priority:        45

  # system headers (top level)
  - Regex:           '^<[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.h>'
    Priority:        50
  # system headers (sub-dirs)
  - Regex:           '^<.*>'
    Priority:        55

Standard:                                       Cpp11
...
```

Focusing just on the include ordering, **clang-format** produces this:

```cpp
#include "Platform.hh"
#include "ZMQconfig.hh"
#include "ZMQendpoint.hh"
#include "ZMQmixin.hh"
#include "Foo/bar.hh"
#include "icd/NavPoint.hh"
#include "icd/Published.hh"
#include "util/Application.hh"
#include <json/json.h>
#include <filesystem>
```

As you can see, the blocks have been merged and the rules applied. Now, if I try to disable clang-format, just around the header blocks:

```cpp
// clang-format off
#include "util/Application.hh"
#include "ZMQmixin.hh"
// clang-format on

#include <filesystem>
#include <json/json.h>

#include "ZMQconfig.hh"
#include "ZMQendpoint.hh"
#include "Platform.hh"

#include "Foo/bar.hh"

#include "icd/Published.hh"
#include "icd/NavPoint.hh"
```

include sorting is completely disabled. In playing with this, I noticed that a comment at the end of a block inhibits block merging but not block sorting:

```cpp
#include "ZMQmixin.hh"
#include "util/Application.hh"
// clang-format on

#include "Platform.hh"
#include "ZMQconfig.hh"
#include "ZMQendpoint.hh"
#include "Foo/bar.hh"
#include "icd/NavPoint.hh"
#include "icd/Published.hh"
#include <json/json.h>
#include <filesystem>
```

This is pretty close; I have very few instances of multiple inheritance where the sorting of base classes is problematic.

Is there a better way? Something I'm missing?